# Java Serializable: Must E be serializable in ArrayList<E>?

Tags: java, serializable

I have the following class containing the fields specified below. My question is, must Admin, Worker and all my other self-defined classes implement Serializable for MyClass to be Serializable?

```
public class MyClass implements java.io.Serializable {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
  ArrayList<Admin> admins;
  ArrayList<Worker> workers;
  ArrayList<Manager> managers;
  ArrayList<Secretary> secretaries;
  ArrayList<Category> categories;
  HashMap<Issue, HashMap<Category,Manager>> ManagedIssues;
  private static MyClass instance;
      ...
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My question is, must Admin, Worker and all my other self-defined classes implement Serializable for MyClass to be Serializable?

Yes. They have to be.

`ArrayList` is already implements `Serializable` interface by default. But you need to implement Serializable interface for the types you are using.

> Serializability of a class is enabled by the class implementing the [`java.io.Serializable interface`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html). Classes that do not implement this interface will not have any of their state serialized or deserialized. All subtypes of a serializable class are themselves serializable.

Answer (score 2):

As others have stated, if a class is marked `Serializable`, then everything inside needs to be marked `Serializable` too.

But in this case also, you really need to make sure you limit mutability of internal state. In other words, when taking a mutable object (like `ArrayList`) in (a constructor or a setter) or returning it (in a getter), make copies to protect the internal state of `MyClass`. This is always a good practice but especially so with `Serializable`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

If you don't want that stuff to be serialized, mark it as `transient`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are making a class serializable, then you have to make sure that everything falling in that class is also serializable. So you must make them serializable first.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but only if thoses lists / map are not empty. In this case serialization mechanizm will try to serialize collections' content.